# Import data from excel file in to model with validations and associations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to use to import data for model associations

This is my case:

```
class SampleRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :sample_request_text_excerpt
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sample_request_text_excerpt
end

class SampleRequestTextExcerpt < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sample_request
end
```

In the sample_request model, asset type field would be text and image , for text type different excel sheet and for image type different excel sheet , only certain field would be extra in the sample_request_text_excerpt model.

For single model no issues , while try to use for associations

this line showing error:

```
 sample_request.attributes = row.to_hash
```

while uploading the text spreadsheet error displayed.

Comment: It would be helpful to see what the actual error is that the line `sample_request.attributes = row.to_hash` is throwing.

Comment: Thank you for replying                                          I'm getting this error  Unknown attributeError stock_id , this field belongs to the SampleRequestTextExcerpt table attributes (child table).

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting the attributes for your `sample_request` object, you are using a hash.  In that hash there is a key, `stock_id` and when Rails tries to set that attribute for your `sample_request` object it can't find it.  This is most likely because there isn't a column for `stock_id` on your sample_request model.

In order to solve this you either need to:

1) Remove the `stock_id` key from the hash.  You can use [.delete](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-delete) to accomplish this.

2) Or, you can add `stock_id` to your `sample_request` model.